# How to handle Twilio postbacks in Cloud9 IDE dev server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twilio, cloud9-ide

I'm building a Rails app in Cloud9 IDE, and part of the application involves interactive voice response. The end-user calls the Twilio phone number, and then Twilio POSTs into the Rails app.

The app is working fine when deployed on Heroku, but the deployment process is an extra step. I would like to point Twilio directly at the app running in Cloud9, but it doesn't work. Cloud9 requires one to be logged in to access the dev-server URL, and Twilio can't log in.

Is there a way to tell Cloud9 not to require login to access my dev server? I'd love to just make an edit, click run, call my Twilio number and test. As it is now, I have to git commit and deploy to Heroku on each iteration.

Help! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a private workspace, you can enable your app to be accessible publicly by clicking the 'Share' menu, and making your application public. Doing so will not make your project public, but your running server would become accessible without authentication.

[image]